# Typescript void is not assignable to parameter type ProcedureListener

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to call a function inside my class but I receive the following warning / error on this part:

```
rpc.register('cBrowser-SetUrl', (url: string, enableCursor: boolean) => {
    this.setBrowserUrl(url, enableCursor);
});
```

The error is the following:
[image]

Full code:

```
const rpc = require('rage-rpc');

class BrowserSingleton {
    browser: BrowserMp;

    constructor() {
        this.browser = mp.browsers.new(' http://package/cef/index.html');

        rpc.register('cBrowser-SetUrl', (url: string, enableCursor: boolean) => {
            this.setBrowserUrl(url, enableCursor);
        });
    }

    setBrowserUrl(url: string, enableCursor: boolean) {
        const path = `app.$router.push('${url}');`;

        this.setInteractState(enableCursor);
        this.pasteJS(path);
    }

    pasteJS(data: string) {
        this.browser.execute(data);
    }

    setInteractState(state: boolean) {
        mp.gui.cursor.visible = state;
        mp.game.ui.displayRadar(!state);
        mp.gui.chat.show(!state);
        mp.nametags.enabled = !state;
    }
}

new BrowserSingleton();
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I appreciate any kind of help and suggestions.

Comment: The second argument argument to the callback is of type `ProcedureListenerInfo`, not of type `boolean`. `export type ProcedureListener = (args: any, info: ProcedureListenerInfo) => any;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function of `rpc.register()` has two parameters `args` and `info`. If you want to correctly call this function you need to declare the callback like this.

```
rpc.register('cBrowser-SetUrl', (args: any, info: ProcedureListenerInfo) => {
  this.setBrowserUrl(url, enableCursor);
});
```

The two arguments `url` and `enableCursor` are not available in the constructor yet. I suggest adding those to the `constructor` signature or put the `register` call inside the `setBrowserURL` function.